# Sum values from select strsplit column in dataframe in R

Tags: r, plyr, dplyr, tidyr

Suppose I have a data frame in `R` with two columns: `value` and `my_letters`:

```
> my_foo
   value  my_letters
1      5     d f h b
2      3 j f i a b g
3      1   d g j f i
4      1     h i b e
5      4       c d a
6      6     i d j e
7      7     b h f i
8      5       h d g
9     10   h e i f a
10     3     h g d i
```

Each element of `my_letters`is 3-6 **non-repeating** letters, separated by spaces.

I can count how often each letter occurs:

```
> table( unlist( strsplit( as.character(my_foo$my_letters), " " ) ) )

a b c d e f g h i j 
3 4 1 6 3 5 4 6 7 3
```

But what if I want a *weighted* sum by `value`?

So, `a` appears three times: in row 2 with value 3, row 5 with value 4, row 9 with value 10.  So for `a` I want to see 3 + 4 + 10 = 17.
(note that `value` *may* repeat)

Is there a nice `plyr`/`dplyr`/`tidyr` way to do this? (or even `apply`...)

Thank you!!

Code to generate this data frame (which I'm sure there's a neater way to do):

```
library( plyr )

set.seed(1)
foo    <- replicate( 10, letters[ sample( 10, sample(3:6, 1), replace = F ) ] )
foo2   <- laply( foo, function(d) paste(d, collapse = " ") )
my_foo <- data.frame( value=sample(10, replace=T), my_letters = foo2 )
my_foo

# count how often each letter appears
table( unlist( strsplit( as.character(my_foo$my_letters), " " ) ) )
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use `cSplit` from my "splitstackshape" package:

```
library(splitstackshape)
cSplit(my_foo, "my_letters", " ", "long")[, sum(value), by = my_letters]
#     my_letters V1
#  1:          d 24
#  2:          f 26
#  3:          h 31
#  4:          b 16
#  5:          j 10
#  6:          i 31
#  7:          a 17
#  8:          g 12
#  9:          e 17
# 10:          c  4
```

---

By the way, here's an alternative to your `table` line:

```
cSplit(my_foo, "my_letters", " ", "long")[, .N, by = my_letters]
```

---

#### Update -- Benchmarks

@nicola's base solution is nice, but it doesn't scale well. A better alternative would be to use:

```
xtabs(rep(as.numeric(my_foo$value), vapply(myletters, length, 1L) ~
      unlist(myletters, use.names = FALSE))
```

The `as.numeric` becomes important if you expect the summed values to be very large, at which point `xtabs` would give you integer overflow errors.

Here are some functions to compare:

```
fun1 <- function() {
  myletters <- strsplit( as.character(my_foo$my_letters), " ", TRUE)
  xtabs(rep(as.numeric(my_foo$value), 
            vapply(myletters, length, 1L)) ~ unlist(myletters))
}

fun2 <- function() cSplit(my_foo, "my_letters", " ", "long")[, sum(value), by = my_letters]

fun3a <- function() {
  myletters<-strsplit( as.character(my_foo$my_letters), " " )
  table(unlist(mapply(rep,myletters,my_foo$value)))
}

fun3b <- function() {
  myletters<-strsplit( as.character(my_foo$my_letters), " " , TRUE)
  table(unlist(mapply(rep,myletters,my_foo$value)))
}
```

Here's the sample data. Change `n` to experiment with different sizes. We'll start with a modest 1,000 rows.

```
library( plyr )
set.seed(1)
n <- 1000
foo    <- replicate(n, letters[ sample( 10, sample(3:6, 1), replace = F ) ] )
foo2   <- laply( foo, function(d) paste(d, collapse = " ") )
my_foo <- data.frame( value=sample(n, replace=T), my_letters = foo2 )
```

Initial timings:

```
system.time(fun1())
#    user  system elapsed 
#   0.006   0.000   0.006 
system.time(fun2())
#    user  system elapsed 
#   0.013   0.000   0.013 
system.time(fun3a())
#    user  system elapsed 
#   0.844   0.024   0.870 
system.time(fun3b())
#    user  system elapsed 
#   0.533   0.020   0.561
```

Here are some timings with `n <- 100000` before making the sample data:

```
system.time(fun1())
#    user  system elapsed 
#   0.911   0.004   0.916 
system.time(fun2())
#    user  system elapsed 
#   0.537   0.004   0.551
```

Comment: Neat package, worth looking into!

Comment: Great job. Maybe an improvement can be obtained through `tapply`: `large<-data.frame(x=rep(as.numeric(my_foo$value),vapply(myletters, length, 1L)),y=unlist(myletters));tapply(large$x,large$y,sum)`. This seems quite faster than `fun1`.

Answer (score 3):

A `base` R solution:

```
    myletters<-strsplit( as.character(my_foo$my_letters), " " )
    table(unlist(mapply(rep,myletters,my_foo$value)))
```

Comment: Nice, you beat me to it ;)  Seems `base` is out of favour, for some reason.

Comment: This might also be worth considering for the second line: `xtabs(rep(my_foo$value, vapply(myletters, length, 1L)) ~ unlist(myletters))`.

Comment: love the `base` mentality.. slight concern about `rep` if `value` is high (which obviously was not the case in original question). @AnandaMahto that is nice!

Comment: @AnandaMahto Great comment. I guess your solution is more efficient than mine.

Comment: @nicola, it should be much more efficient as the dataset grows since you'll be dealing with shorter vectors. Also, be sure to use `fixed = TRUE` whenever possible with `strsplit`--it tends to be a lot faster.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a `base R` solution

```
 table(scan(text=with(my_foo,my_letters[rep(1:nrow(my_foo),
                      value)]), sep='', what='', quiet=TRUE))

 # a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h  i  j 
 #17 16  4 24 17 26 12 31 31 10
```

Or `count` from `dplyr`

```
lst <- strsplit( as.character(my_foo$my_letters), " " ) 
library(dplyr)
devtools::install_github("hadley/tidyr")
library(tidyr)
 unnest(setNames(lst, my_foo$value), val) %>%
                                      mutate(val=as.numeric(val)) %>%
                                      count(x, wt=val)
 #   x  n
 #1  a 17
 #2  b 16
 #3  c  4
 #4  d 24
 #5  e 17
 #6  f 26
 #7  g 12
 #8  h 31
 #9  i 31
 #10 j 10
```

Comment: Ah, CRAN still on v0.1, behind github 0.1.0.9

Comment: @akrun, feel free to update my benchmarks with your solutions if you would like. I haven't updated "tidyr" in a while so I don't seem to have `unnest`.

Comment: @sai sorry I thought, the `unnest` is already on CRAN version

Comment: @akrun, Thank you, this is great--and uses `plyr`/`tidyr` as in original question. I'd Accept this answer as well if I could.